# Show only specific list item from many

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this

**HTML**

```
<p class="showOnlyChoose"> Show </p>

<ul>
  <li>Not Taken</li>
  <li>Not Taken</li>
  <li class="Choose">Taken</li>
  <li>Not Taken</li>
  <li class="Choose">Taken</li>
  <li>Not Taken</li>

</ul>
```

What I am wanting is if I click on the **Show** only the **Taken** list will show and others will hide. I searched but did not find good results. Also is this possible with jQuery ? I am not very good in jQuery. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `(p.showOnlyChoose).click(function(){ $("ul li").hide(); $("ul li.Choose").show();});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$('.showOnlyChoose').click(function(){
    $('li').toggle();
    $('li.Choose').show();
    var current_text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(current_text == "Show" ? "Show" : "Hide"); 
});
```

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/H2Gcm/)**

And when you want to get them back just use: `$('li').show();`

Comment: Can it make little more Dynamic like When Click Show it will show only Taken and "SHow " convert into "HIDE" and if I click into "HIDE" all list item will show and "HIDE "will convert into "SHOW" again ?

Comment: @SRaihan: see my answer below to add functionality to switch between "Show" and "Hide" text as well.

Comment: @SRaihan, I updated my answer. I made a version that only changes the text you clicked, no need for extra html.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.showOnlyChoose').on('click', function() {
   $('li.Choose').show().siblings().hide();       
   // $('li').hide().filter('.Choose').show();
})
```

Comment: Thanks ! but How can it be shown again after I made the hide?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the paragraph to **toggle** the "Not Taken" rows and change "Show" to "Hide" (and vice versa), use:

```
$('.showOnlyChoose').on('click', function() {
    $('li').toggle();                               //show or hide all items
    $('li.Choose').show();                          //show .Choose items
    if ($('.showOnlyChoose').html() == 'Show') {    //if paragraph says "Show" change to "Hide"...
        $('.showOnlyChoose').html('Hide');
    }
    else $('.showOnlyChoose').html('Show');         //...otherwise change "Hide" to "Show"
})
```

EDIT: Added "Show"/"Hide" functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select elements by its content you can use $(selector).text()

```
$(".showOnlyChoose").click(function() {
   $("ul li").each(function(){
       if($(this).text() !=  'Taken') {
          $(this).hide();
       }
   });
});
```

If you want to select by class:

```
$(".showOnlyChoose").click(function() {
   $("ul li").each(function(){
      if(!$(this).hasClass("Choose") {
          $(this).hide();
      }
   });
});
```